# mysql query where clause using AND and OR

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone help me with this query:

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
          FROM Punches
          WHERE Serial LIKE '%123%'
          OR Badge LIKE '%123%'
          OR Search_Date LIKE '%123%'
          OR Punch_Time LIKE '%123%'
          OR Device_Name LIKE '%%'
          AND Company_ID = '0002'
          LIMIT 0, 20
```

Essentially I want to search all these fields that are LIKE 123 BUT have to have Company_ID = '0002'. This query returns rows that do not have a Company_ID = '0002'

Comment: Use some parenthesis. Basically add one pair around all the `OR` conditions.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
 SELECT 
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
 FROM 
    Punches
 WHERE 
    (Company_ID = '0002') AND 
    (Serial LIKE '%123%'
     OR Badge LIKE '%123%'
     OR Search_Date LIKE '%123%'
     OR Punch_Time LIKE '%123%'
     OR Device_Name LIKE '%%')
 LIMIT 0, 20
```

Answer (score 1):

1) `AND` has a higher priority than `OR`. Just add parentheses:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
          FROM Punches
          WHERE (... OR ... OR ...)
          AND Company_ID = '0002'
          LIMIT 0, 20
```

2) `Device_Name LIKE '%%'` is always true.